# IF DATE in cell, return Date; IF cell is blank or has text, return N/A or Blank

Tags: excel-2010

EXCEL 2010 - I need a formula in cell `W5` that will return what's in cell `H5` which is either:
a short date (7/4/2019) or blank or text.
*i.e.*  If cell `H5` has a date, return date; if cell `H5` is blank *OR* has text (anything other than a date), return `N/A` or even leave it blank.
I know this is probably easy but can't seem to get it correct.  If needed, the date range will be `7/4/2019` thru `7/26/2019`).
As a side note, I will be using this formula in 2 areas and need dates to be in correct format because they will then be used to subtract to get days between.

Comment: Sorry - KDavis - guess i'm not proficient enough to quite understand your answer.

Comment: Below example - I would need B1 to be a blank cell (or n/a), B2 would be 1/20/2018, and B3 again would be a blank cell (or n/a).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment since you didn't comment on my answer. But I've updated the answer to show how you can add this custom UDF.

Comment: Not adding this as a full answer as it doesn't check if the number entered in the cell is actually a date (even the number 0 can be formatted as a short date):  `=IF(OR(ISTEXT(H5),ISBLANK(H5)),NA(),H5)`

Comment: Have updated my "not an answer" answer - `=IF(OR(ISTEXT(H5),ISBLANK(H5),H5<43650,H5>43672),NA(),H5)`.  It will now return `#N/A` if the entered value is before 4th July '19 (43650) or later than 26th July '19 (43672).

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done with a custom UDF.

```vb
Public Function bIsDate(rng As Range) As Boolean

    If isDate(rng) Then bIsDate = True

End Function
```

> To create a custom UDF, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In Excel, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBE.
> 2. Go to **Insert** > **Module**
> 3. Paste the above code into the new window and exit the VBE
> 4. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Excel to open up the **SaveAs** dialog box
> 5. Save it as a **Macro-Enabled Workbook**
>
> Now you have a brand-new worksheet function `bIsDate()`. You can go into any cell and type in `=bIsDate()` and you will now see it autocomplete.

[image]

Place this in your **W5 Cell**:

```
=If(bIsDate($H5), $H5, "")
```

Comment: KDavis - got it.  VBE and macro-enabled files are little bit above me, but worked perfectly.  Thanks for dumbing down....

Comment: Glad to help, @Marie